# what is the angle position of an object?

Tags: word-choice

ok, look at this iPhone picture.
[image]

Can I say give the image a name as "The Angle Look of the iPhone 5S"?

or the "Side Look of the iPhone 5S" or "Top-DOwn look of the iPhone 5S"

I couldn't find the term that expresses precisely the look of the picture?

Comment: This may not be a suitable question, although I'm happy to be proven wrong - this seems like it will be too broad, or have too many possible answers. Also, I _highly_ doubt there is a single word that expresses this meaning, though again, I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often referred to as an ***angle-on view***.  It follows in the same vein as the terms *head-on* and *side-on*.

See [this](http://trainlife.com/articles/126/modeling-a-new-york-central-bay-window-steel-caboose) website for an example usage. (search the page for *angle-on*)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use 'look' here, this sounds like you're referring to a style rather than a perspective, instead use 'view'

The most suitable for the image, say if your wanted to save it and find it again easily in a file on your PC or you wanted to name the image on a website would be...

The angular view of the iPhone 5S 
Or
An angular view of the iPhone 5S

As Jim says, there are plenty. But this would be appropriate for the examples of use I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try, "viewed from above at an angle?"

or a "[Birds-eye view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%27s-eye_view)"?